# Interpolating a 3-dim (time, lat, lon) field with _FillValue in Python. How to avoid for loops?

Tags: python, scipy, remap

I am interpolating data from the oceanic component of CMIP6 models to a 2x2 grid. The field has a dim of (time, nav_lat, nav_lon) and nan values in continent. Here, nav_lon and nav_lat are two-dimensional curvilinear grid. I can do the interpolation using griddata from scipy, but I have to use a loop over time. The loop makes it pretty slow if the data has thousands of time records. My question is how to vectorize the interpolation over time.

The following is my code:

```
import xarray as xr
import numpy as np
from scipy.interpolate import griddata
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

source = xr.open_dataset('data/zos_2850.nc',decode_times=False)

# obtain old lon and lat (and put lon in 0-360 range)
# nav_lon is from -180 to 180, not in 0-360 range
loni, lati = source.nav_lon.values%360, source.nav_lat.values

# flatten the source coordinates
loni_flat, lati_flat = loni.flatten(), lati.flatten()

# define a 2x2 lon-lat grid
lon, lat = np.linspace(0,360,181), np.linspace(-90,90,91) 

# create mesh
X, Y = np.meshgrid(lon,lat)

# loop over time
ntime = len(source.time)
tmp = []
for t in range(ntime):  
    print(t)
    var_s = source.zos[t].values
    var_s_flat = var_s.flatten()

    # index indicates where they are valid values
    index = np.where(~np.isnan(var_s_flat))
    # remap the valid values to the new grid 
    var_t = griddata((loni_flat[index],lati_flat[index]),var_s_flat[index], (X,Y), 
    method='cubic')
    
    # interpolate mask using nearest
    maskinterp = griddata((loni_flat,lati_flat),var_s_flat, (X,Y), method='nearest')
    # re-mask interpolated data
    var_t[np.isnan(maskinterp)] = np.nan

tmp.append(var_t)

# convert to DataArray
da = xr.DataArray(data=tmp, 
              dims=["time","lat","lon"], 
              coords=dict(lon=(["lon"], lon),lat=(["lat"], lat),time=source['time']))
```

Comment: I don't work with grid data but I wonder if you could project each time period onto a sub-patch of a larger grid, e.g. with pseudo-continents separating each time patch from the next.